# Trying to delete a role from Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity

I am trying to delete a role from my RoleManager, and I get the error

> The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager.

**My Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void DeleteRole(string RoleName)
    {
        var RoleMan = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        IdentityRole Role = new IdentityRole();
        Role.Name = RoleName;
        RoleMan.Delete(Role);
    }
```

Comment: Is your ApplicationDbContext() the context that ASP.NET Identity is using?  In a lot of my apps Identity has its own context... often called IdentityContext.

Comment: I've never seen someone create an entity (Role) that isn't attached to the context and simply delete it.  How is that even suppose to work?  How does EF know what Role you've provided is what Role exists in the database?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try use find by name method in rolemanager

```
var role = roleManager.FindByName(RoleName);
roleManager.Delete(role);
```